# Sort of a knock when starting the car only once

Tags: engine, audi, knock

I have an `Audi A3 2007 2.0 tdi`, the oil still valable for more than 4000km to be changed, today, since the morning when i start the car i hear a single knock in the bottom, the knock happens only one time after i start the car.

Help please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question. I don't readily see what you're trying to solve. I get that you have a single knock ... but what exactly do you need information about?

Comment: Hello, thank's for answering and for the welcome, i just want to know what is the problem and if i cant drive the car for atleast 100km to find someone to fix it

Comment: To ensure I understand, you're saying you hear the noise on first startup, then quickly afterward it goes away? You don't hear it again all day long no matter if you restart the vehicle?

Comment: hello, at each start i hear a single knock, i drive normal, when i restart car again i hear only one knock

Comment: How long have you been experiencing this? Is there anyway to create a video of the single knock? It doesn't matter how long the engine runs, you still hear the "single knock" each time you start it? What I'm asking here is, if you start it up, then shut it off within a few seconds, then restart, you still hear the knock and it only happens one time?

Comment: What brand of oil filter did you use?

Comment: Yes correct if you start and stop then start again you will always hear the first knock, i repaired it by changing the flywheel and clutch kit. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: in my case, I changed the Flywheel and the clutch kit.